# Why isn't getchar exiting?

Tags: c, getchar

I wrote a program to try and print a 2D table containing a graphical representation of user input using a 2D array in C. I compile and run this program, but not matter how much I press Return or Ctrl+D for EOF, getchar does not appear to yeilding to the instructions in the loop as expected. What am I doing wrong here?

```
int main()
{
    /*ignore these comments, they are outdated todo lists*/
    /* make vars init here, change for to while */
    /* finish printing */
    int c;
    int i, sec, other;
    char ndigit[3][8];

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n' || '\t' || ' ') {
            for(i = 0; i < 63; ndigit[1][i] += 1);
                ;
        }
        else if (c >= '0' || c <= '9') {
            for(sec = 0; sec < 63; ndigit[2][sec] += 1)
                ;
        }
        else
            for(other = 0; other < 63; ndigit[3][other] += 1)
                ;
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= 3; ++i)
        for (sec = 0; sec <= 8; sec++)
            printf("%s\n", ndigit[i][sec]);
}
```

Comment: 1) `c == '\n' || '\t' || ' '` always true. 2) unchange index variable. 3) out of bounds.

Comment: Why the John Doe name? I invite you to register on Stack Overflow with your real identity (and some way to join you).

Answer (score 1):

Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`, notably on Linux, which I recommend for beginners and experts). You'll probably get many useful warnings from your compiler (if possible use a recent version of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), since GCC is improving its diagnostics over time....). Improve your code till you get no warnings at all. Then **use a debugger** (`gdb`), notably to run your program step by step. Perhaps add some debug prints. You might be interested in also using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and the [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer).

Notice that in:

```
 for(other = 0; other < 63; ndigit[3][other] += 1);
```

`other` is not changing (you might forgot an `other++`, and then you'll get a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) if you add it, because `ndigit[`*i*`][`*j*`]` makes sense only for 0 <= *i* < 3 and 0 <= *j* < 8); so you have an infinite loop.

A [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) is one way to have [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (UB). You should **be *very scared* of UB** and work very hard to avoid UB. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) I explain why.

Comment: You were right, I did forget to increment the variables, and I did in fact get a segfault after adding the increment to the loop. However, I am confused as to why I got a segfault when I had other < 63 in the for loop's conditions. How is this possible?